# Strange output of the Scala compiler in Spray project

Tags: scala, spray, shapeless

I have a mixed Scala/Java Maven project that uses Spray.
I compile with Maven and the scala-maven-plugin.
I'm using Scala 2.10.4.
Maven outputs a lot of meaningless information about Shapeless, a dependency of Spray:

```
[INFO] Compiling 25 Scala sources and 841 Java sources to /home/david/myproject/WEB- INF/classes...
Nothing <: spray.routing.Directive1[spray.http.Uri]?
true
spray.routing.Directive1[spray.http.Uri] <: shapeless.HList?
false
spray.routing.Directive1[spray.http.Uri] <: L?
false
Nothing <: spray.routing.Directive1[spray.http.Uri]?
true
spray.routing.Directive1[spray.http.Uri] <: shapeless.HList?
false
spray.routing.Directive1[spray.http.Uri] <: L?
false
Unit <: spray.httpx.marshalling.Marshaller[(spray.http.StatusCodes.ServerError, String)]?
false
Unit <: akka.event.LoggingAdapter?
false
Nothing <: spray.routing.Directive0?
true
spray.routing.Directive0 <: shapeless.HList?
false
spray.routing.Directive0 <: L?
false
Nothing <: spray.routing.Directive0?
true
spray.routing.Directive0 <: shapeless.HList?
false
spray.routing.Directive0 <: L?
false
Nothing <: spray.routing.Directive1[java.util.Locale]?
true
spray.routing.Directive1[java.util.Locale] <: shapeless.HList?
false
spray.routing.Directive1[java.util.Locale] <: L?
false
Nothing <: spray.routing.Directive1[java.util.Locale]?
true
spray.routing.Directive1[java.util.Locale] <: shapeless.HList?
false
spray.routing.Directive1[java.util.Locale] <: L?
false
Nothing <: spray.routing.Directive[shapeless.HNil]?
true
spray.routing.Directive[shapeless.HNil] <: shapeless.HList?
false
spray.routing.Directive[shapeless.HNil] <: L?
false
Nothing <: spray.routing.Directive[shapeless.HNil]?
true
spray.routing.Directive[shapeless.HNil] <: shapeless.HList?
false
spray.routing.Directive[shapeless.HNil] <: L?
false
Nothing <: spray.routing.Directive[shapeless.HNil]?
true
spray.routing.Directive[shapeless.HNil] <: shapeless.HList?
false
spray.routing.Directive[shapeless.HNil] <: L?
false
Nothing <: spray.routing.Directive[shapeless.HNil]?
true
spray.routing.Directive[shapeless.HNil] <: shapeless.HList?
false
spray.routing.Directive[shapeless.HNil] <: L?
false
Nothing <: spray.routing.Directive[shapeless.::[fcc.vision.rest.Usuario,shapeless.HNil]]?
true
spray.routing.Directive[shapeless.::[fcc.vision.rest.Usuario,shapeless.HNil]] <: shapeless.HList?
...
```

This generates a lot of noise, and provides no meaning to me.

What is the purpose of this messages?

They look like internal debug output of the Scala compiler.

Can they be removed?.

**UPDATE:**

Here is an excerpt of my pom:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.spray</groupId>
        <artifactId>spray-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.spray</groupId>
        <artifactId>spray-routing</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json4s</groupId>
        <artifactId>json4s-native_${scala.mayor}</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scalap</artifactId>
        <version>${scala.mayor}.${scala.menor}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.typesafe.akka</groupId>
        <artifactId>akka-actor_${scala.mayor}</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
        <version>${scala.mayor}.${scala.menor}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <scala.mayor>2.10</scala.mayor>
    <scala.menor>4</scala.menor>
</properties>
```

Shapeless is brought as a transitive dependency automatically.

Comment: Can you should your dependencies for Spray and Shapeless?

Comment: Could you reduce this down to a simple code example which causes the error? What you've provided doesn't give enough clues to decipher your issue.

Comment: Thanks for your interest. When I have time, I'll try to isolate to the simplest possible project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like you have `-explaintypes` enabled in your Scala compiler options. Open your `pom.xml` and check the `<plugin><plugins>` entry for `scala-maven-scala`. See if in `<configuration><args>` you have `<arg>-explaintypes</arg>`. These messages can sometimes aid in cleaning up type errors in your code but I find them too annoying to keep them on all the time, just remove the `<arg>-explaintypes</arg>` and they should go away (check with other team members if they put it there for some reason).

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't expect that argument to dump info so meaningless for me.

Comment: Neither did I the first time I set it :)